# AWS lambda can't find lambda layer path

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I am having a tough time setting up the lambda layers with lambdas. I am using **node 14**.

My folder structure for lambda layer

```
   layer/ 
     nodejs/
      node14/
        node_modules/
            hey.js
```

I have also tried having only the nodejs directory as below

```
layer/
   nodejs/
    hey.js
```

But in both cases I get cannot found module error in the lambda.

The paths I tried for accessing layers in lambda are as below

```
'/opt/nodejs/node14/node_modules/hey.js' (for first folder structure)
'/opt/nodejs/hey.js' (for folder structure with only the nodejs directory in the layer)
'hey.js' (trying to access the file directly)
```

But I had no luck. What am I doing wrong?

I am using AWS sam to deploy lambda and layers. I could see the layer getting attached to lambda on the console.

Here is my SAM template

```
    layer1:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
        Properties:
          ContentUri: ./src/lambda-layers/layer1
          CompatibleRuntimes:
            - nodejs14.x
        Metadata:
          BuildMethod: nodejs14.x

lambda1:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src/lambdas/lambda1
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Layers:
        - !Ref layer1
      Events:
        AwsIoTMetadata:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref CrApi
            Path: /user
            Method: GET
```

How to access the layer in lambda?

Please Help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, in your lambda, you access your layer as follows:

```
const MyLayer = require("mylayer"); // Where the package name is your layer's package name as set in your package.json
```

Example layer code:

```
class MyLayer {    }
module.exports = MyLayer;
```

Layer folder structure:

```
mylayer/nodejs/node_modules/mylayer/
// Inside should be your package.json, package-lock.json and your code file
```

Cloudformation template:

```
MyLayer:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
  Properties:
    ContentUri: ./mylayer
    CompatibleRuntimes:
      - nodejs
    LicenseInfo: MIT
    RetentionPolicy: Retain
```

Also make sure that your Lambda is also nodejs14